# Chamar função PHP em uma classe

Tags: php, javascript

Boa tarde, estou criando um sistema simples em PHPOO com MVC e gostaria de executar uma função dentro do controller com uma chamada do jquery. Não quero chamado o controller no html, quero que um js faça esse trabalho pra mim.
Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:
Meu controller fica em controller/UsersController.
Classe:

```
<?php
class UserController{
   public function teste(){
       echo "ok";
   }
}
?>
```

e o JS:

```
$("#btn-login").click(function(){
        var data = $("#login-form").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'UserController.php', 
            data : data,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function()
            {   
                $("#btn-login").html('Validando ...');
            },
            success :  function(response){                      
                if(response.codigo == "1"){ 
                    $("#btn-login").html('Entrar');
                    $("#login-alert").css('display', 'none')
                    window.location.href = "home.php";
                }
                else{           
                    $("#btn-login").html('Entrar');
                    $("#login-alert").css('display', 'block')
                    $("#mensagem").html('<strong>Erro! </strong>' + response.mensagem);
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Quero executar a função teste dentro da Classe.

Grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Fazer uma requisição para o arquivo que apenas define a classe não faz sentido. Você precisa ter no PHP a instanciação da classe e a execução do método desejado. O JavaScript não conseguirá instanciar e chamar um método do PHP de forma automática.

Comment: Eu tive o mesmo problema um tempo atrás, a solução que encontrei foi adicionar um atributo dentro do post(que esta enviado) com o nome da função passada, em seguida criei uma classe de fronteira que não tem função, que serve para verificar o post, e chamar a função do php.
Sei que não é a resposta que espera, mais se não encontrar uma solução fica como uma dica, vou ficar de olho na sua pergunta, as respostas podem me ajudar também.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, achei esse tutorial https://luis4raujo.wordpress.com/2015/08/24/desenvolvendo-com-php-orientado-a-objeto-usando-a-arquitetura-mvc-e-requisicao-ajax/ mas não consegui fazer funcionar pois tenho pouco conhecimento.